`mv dir/file1 ..` removed file completely
Being in ~/dir1, I wanted to move the file ~/dir1/subdir1/file1 into ~. I executed mv subdir1/file1 ... No error occured. ~/dir1/subdir1 is empty, but I cannot find the file file1. Not in ~ and not in ~/dir.
Being in ~ and having the file ~/dir2/file2, when executing mv dir2/file2 .., I get the error message
mv: cannot move 'dir2/file2' to '../file2': Permission denied

which is understandable as .. is the /home directory where I have no rights to write.
I am a little bit confused as the mv command seems to have different behaviours on my linux installation. Furthermore, I wonder if I can get back my first file (file1) as I accidentally deleted an important file that way.

I missed something initially: ~/dir1 was not a directory of its own but a symlink to another directory. Hence, being in ~/dir1, .. does not resolve to ~, but to the parent of the original directory. Thus, I moved the file there, where I also was able to find the file file1.
